# Why do I get a fatal error with this htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm getting this error when I try to upload a new plugin in wordpress, The Uploaded File Exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` Directive in `php.ini` so I decided to update the `.htaccess` file by adding this line at the bottom: `php_value upload_max_filesize 256M`

When I do so, I get a fatal error and the site won't load.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

`.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP.INI is a php config file, while .HTACCESS is apache per folder config file. Maybe your host doesn't allow changing the php values, so 1st try to locate your php.ini file and put your code there - upload_max_filesize 256M. If you dont have it create 1. If this doesn't help, contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your hosting is from shared hosting provider. The size issue is solved from php.ini folder as its config for PHP on server. .HTACCESS on other hands allows administrators to specify options for individual directories. In wordpress its major task is to controls how your site’s permalinks are displayed